# removing multple line base on regex search

Tags: sed

how can I remove number of line based on regex search?
for example :
if i have a file :

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
bbb
eee
```

I would like to remove the line that contains "bbb" string and the line after it . so the result should look like :

```
aaa
ddd
```

Comment: Hi, have a look at this :http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, check samples.

Answer (score 5):

`addr1,+N` Will match `addr1` and the `N` lines following `addr1`.

```
$ sed '/bbb/,+1d' file.txt 
aaa
ddd
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with this,

```
sed '/bbb/{N;d;}' your_file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
printf "aaa\nbbb\nccc\nddd\neee" | sed '/bbb/,1+d'
```

outputs

```
aaa
ddd
eee
```